# BLOB update is not working, not showing error also but it store null

Tags: java

This code stores null in database.

```
  PreparedStatement ps;  
    String preparestmt = "update t_member set photo=? " + " where aplication_num = (select max(application_num) from t_member)";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(preparestmt);  
     ps.setBinaryStream(1,in,in.available());
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();
    in.close();
     con.commit();
     con.close();
```

photo is blob field,in is inputstream that contains image file. In insert image is saved correctly but while i try to update.it always store null only. inputstream is also fine.It has 54353 bytes i checked tat also. help me to update this data.

Comment: why are you setting the application_num as max()? How are your ensuring that this statement would always return your intended application_num?

Comment: tat is not matter i want like tat only.if i update any other column means it updating fine for blob only i asking.

Comment: could you paste your insert statement as well? you said that works.

Comment: @sabarirajan :- am facing same issue while updating image as blob, it is always null and no exception . did you resolved this issue? can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to retrieve the updated image from Java and check it whether it got updated. I hope you are viewing in SQLClient which often shows null for BLOB.

Answer (score 0):

`InputStream.available()` does **NOT** give you the number of bytes in the stream.

It returns the number of bytes that can be read *without blocking*.

[From the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29)

> *Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream **without blocking** by the next invocation of a method for this input stream. [...] 
>
>
>   It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.*

(Emphasis me)

You need to find a different way to calculate the size of your BLOB. If the data is coming from a `File` use, `File.length()`